# Externalizing a module in Angular 2

Tags: angular

So, i was working on my application and i realized that several modules could be extracted to separate libraries, that could be installed via NPM and reused across other applications. The current structure looks like this:

```
app/
    search/
        component1/
        component2/
        component3/
        search.module.ts
        search.service.ts
    login/
    register/
```

Let's say i want to extract `search`, what's the first step? How do i organize this separate repository? Does it also have a `src` dir and a package.json? Is there any specific documentation on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this repo could help you

https://github.com/preboot/angular-library-seed

and this blog post:

http://blog.mgechev.com/2017/01/21/distributing-an-angular-library-aot-ngc-types/

or clone this repo, and custom as you need

https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: Seems a little old, though. Is this still the best practice?

Comment: you could upgrade packages version in package.json file, or clone repo in my updated comment. `Is this still the best practice?` -> yeap, Angular v4 still backward compatible with Angular v2

Answer (score 0):

To build an external module that you can install with npm, you should bundle your source files into a distribution folder, using any one of the several module loader formats available: UMD, CJS, AMD, etc. I recommend UMD as its universally loadable by any module loader.

If you want to have your components to work in an AOT build, you'll need to deploy the JS files along with the metadata files. You should also output .d.ts files - mainly for making code completion support available in the IDE of your choice (i.e. I prefer Vscode)

Here is a seed sample application that demonstrates building a re-usable module for distribution:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-starter-app

https://github.com/pixelbits-mk/ng2-starter-app

The built target to run is:

```
gulp module
```

To publish to npm:

```
npm publish
```

Comment: Why are .d.ts files needed? Can't they be autogenerated from the .ts files i have in the repo?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you the official style guide that recommends you the folder structure and some conventions when creating modules.

https://angular.io/styleguide#!#application-structure-and-angular-modules

additionally as I see you are starting I would also suggest

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

this tool allows you to create modules, components and other staff from command line and follows some rules from the style guide.

Comment: All those conventions are related to your application code, not to library code. As you can see from my example, it perfectly matches Angular's styleguide and is using angular-cli.